# Responsively center two elements on same level

Tags: css

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/w2tbefap/

It's a simple css problem.

I have a two separate elements (div's here).

The two elements have different widths.

I need to responsively center the elements next to each other so it is positioned like in the bottom example. The bottom example is just a centered image.

```
        .block-1{
            border: 1px solid red;
            height: 100px;
        }

        .content{
            border: 1px solid green;
            position: relative;
        }

        .block-1-1{
            background: blue;
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
            //float: left;
            position: absolute;
            right: 50%;
            margin-right: 20px;
        }

        .block-1-2{
            background: yellow;
            width: 300px;
            height: 50px;
            //float: right;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50%;
            //right: 0;
        }



        .block-2{
            border: 1px solid red;
            height: 100px;
        }

        .content-2{

            text-align: center;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS for the blocks, and add `text-align:center;` to `.content`:

```
.block-1-1 {
    background: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.block-1-2 {
    background: yellow;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/w2tbefap/1/)**

Comment: We have the exact same solution! :-)

Comment: @Type-Style - Not really. Mine works, yours doesn't.http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/c3mqrxmx/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use position: absolute; ?

I suggest inline-block:
http://jsfiddle.net/w2tbefap/4/

```
.content{
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.block-1-1, .block-1-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: this solution won't work. if you resize the browser both box will come below to another one..